# Should I use him or himself in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> No one could save the show. Except **him/himself**, the lead singer.

Should I use him or himself? And why? (I always get confused in situations like these.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstances and what you're trying to say.

If you're pointing to or talking about one person specifically, you could say

> No one could save the show except him, the lead singer.

If you're speaking in more general terms about the band, you could say

> No one could save the show except the lead singer himself.

It's a small difference. It would be stylistically awkward, though, to use "himself" the way you have in the sentence. That is not usually seen outside of some dialects, like Irish English.

An example from John Millington Synge's "Playboy of the Western World":

> PHILLY  (turning on JIMMY).  You’re a silly man, Jimmy Farrell. He said his father was a farmer a while since, and there’s **himself** now in a poor state. [emphasis my own]